# is water made by electrolysis considered 'rain' for purposes of mikveh?

Tags: halacha

I understand that water fit for mikveh is usually produced by rainfall. However, there are increasing numbers of municipalities where the collection of rain water is illegal.  If hydrogen and oxygen gas are ignited together by electricity, this produces water.  If said water falls naturally into a mikveh without being channeled or redirected, is this equivalent to rainfall falling into the mikveh?

Comment: probably the most expensive mikva in history you might want to get a huge block of ice from an industrial freezer the size of 5760 eggs clean it up so their is not 18 egg-volume of water and stick it in the bor like everyone else does.